# Convert events from a USB human interface device using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, events, hid

I have a USB HID touchpad that collects input. By default, when I press on the touchpad it generates **carriage return** (Enter) and when I try to use it as a mouse it actually enters a **dragging** state.

What I want to do is to convert the **carriage return** into a **mouse click** event and the **dragging** state into a **cursor move** without the initial clicking part.

I found the [raw input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) alternative. However, I don't know how to convert it into mouse **click** and cursor **move**.

Here is the code responsible with the mouse 'reading':

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mouseProc (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != NULL)
    {
        if(wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            cout<<"clicked"<<endl;
        }
        printf("Mouse position X = %d  Mouse Position Y = %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x,pMouseStruct->pt.y);

        stringstream sx, sy;
        sx << (int) pMouseStruct->pt.x << endl;
        sy << (int) pMouseStruct->pt.y << endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

then the keyboard part:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *str = (tagKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

    cout<<str->vkCode<<endl;

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

then the logging part:

```
DWORD WINAPI MyLogger(LPVOID lpParm)
{

    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, hInstance, NULL );
    hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInstance, NULL );

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I don't know if this is relevant, but I want to use the HID to play in a Chromium instance on a windows system.

Comment: How would your transparent window know, if it should send a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` or a `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` to the window underneath?

Comment: I assumed the transparent window should 'know' send a `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE` (in order to have a better control over the 'output'), yet I didn't consider this to be very important. Should I worry about it?

Comment: A window gets either all input, or none. If you wish to filter input, you'll have to pass some of that input on to windows underneath. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is one of the messages you would want to pass on, and you'll have to decide, whether it should be `WM_MOUSEMOVE` or `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`. `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is another message that's probably impossible to get right, given your proposed configuration with a transparent window.

Comment: I see, thank you. So your advice would be to rule that out and focus on the other two approaches?

Comment: Your code examples are using low-level mouse/keyboard hooks, not raw input.  If you open your device for raw input, do you get RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD structures, or RIM_TYPEHID structures?   (You *should* be getting RIM_TYPEHID.)   Once you've got the HID data, you should be able to parse it out (bypassing the drivers) and call SendInput as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register the hook with WH_MOUSE_LL, the possible values of **wparam** are: ***WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP***, WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, or WM_RBUTTONUP.

I'm expecting that once the *WM_LBUTTONDOWN* is issued, **a corresponding *WM_LBUTTONUP* has to be issued** to prevent the cursor from entering dragging state.

I don't have the device to test this but I would try the call below to prevent entering dragging state.

```
CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, WM_LBUTTONUP, lParam);
```

or use **`mouse_event`** with *MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP* to inject the release of the left button.

I don't think that the raw input alternative is a good idea. I see it as a measure of last resort.

Answer (score 2):

For mouse click and mouse move - when you handle the input from the HID use the **[SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)** method.

The click is easy, for the mouse move try to get the scaled drag coordinates and convert them to the current screen scale coordinates and also use the `SendInput` method.

Also you can track the displacement in x, y and make appropriate calibration to translate them to screen x, y

Answer (score 2):

The touchpad is just a mouse like any other. It generates standard mouse events. Use a global `WH_MOUSE` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to capture mouse events globally. To replay them, use `mouse_event()`. Alternatively, use `WH_JOURNALRECORD` and `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` hooks instead for capture and playback, respectively.